# Order of elements in Semidirect product of groups

Tags: group-theory, semidirect-product

Let $G$ and $H$ be two finite groups, where $H$ acts on $G$ trivially, so that $\eta_h(g)=g$ for all $g\in G$ and $h\in H$, and $G$ acts on $H$ by conjugation.  We want to construct the semi direct product of $G$ and $H$, namely $H\rtimes G$.  Note that we have the multiplication rule $$(h_1, g_1)(h_2, g_2)= (h_1g_1h_2g_1^{-1}, g_1g_2).$$ Is there a "formula" or a way to determine the order of a typical element $(h,g)$?  In particular, is there a way to determine the order of an element of the form $g_1h_2g_1^{-1}$?

As I stated below, the second question is a silly question.  For the order of the element in the semi direct product, $(h,g)$, if you raise it to the power $|h|n$ where $|h|$ divides $n-1$ and $|g|$ divides $n$, then we have that $(h,g)^{|h|n}=(e_H, e_G)$.  So this begs the questions, is the order of the element $(h,g)$ $lcm(|h|, |g|)$? If not, can anyone shed some light on the situation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The second question was a silly question to ask.  Clearly, if $a$ and $b$ are conjugate, then both elements must have the same order since $|a|$ divides  $|b|$ and vice versa.

Comment: To define a semidirect product $H \rtimes G$ you have to specify a homomorphism $G \to {\rm Aut}(H)$. Saying $G$ acts on $H$ by conjugation does not define the action. It is true that, in the resulting semidirect product, the subgroup $G$ acts on $H$ by conjugation, but you have to specify the action first in order to define the semidirect product. Also, there is no action of $H$ of $G$ involved.

Comment: In general, the only thing that you can say about the order of $(h,g)$ is that it is a multiple $ko(h)$ of the order of $h$, where $k$ divides the order of some element of $g$ (not necessarily of $g$).

Comment: Where all of this is coming from, I really do need an action of $H$ onto $G$ since I am really looking at a bicrossed product.  But to say that $G$ acts on $H$ by conjugation defines the automorphism needed here as shown in the multiplication rule.